# What graphs are "unavoidably" Hamiltonian?

Tags: graph-theory

When we try to find a Hamiltonian cycle in $K_{n,n}$, we can start at a vertex, go to any neighbouring vertex, then any neighbouring vertex unused so far and so on. Whatever choices we make, we never get stuck and always get a cycle containing all vertices.

What graphs are "unavoidably" Hamiltonian in the above sense?

Comment: My guess is that only complete graph and circular graphs (graphs where each vertice has exactly two edges) have this property.

Comment: The complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$ also has the property though?